# Creating invisible folders in a set location

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, hide, glob

I am trying to create invisible folders on my pc.

The problem is if my subfolder gets deleted, it does not update.

If I want to add new folders, it will not update unless I delete C:/TVBA each time which is not safe.

It also creates invisible folders where my python script is located and at `C:/TVBA`.

How do I fix this?

```
   try:
        rootpath = r'C:/TVBA'
        os.mkdir(rootpath)
        os.chdir(rootpath)
    except OSError:
        pass
    for sub_folder in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
        try:
            os.mkdir(sub_folder)
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(sub_folder, 2)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It created invisible folders in your current folder because you did not pass  `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW()` the required path. My Python version is 3.6 and I have tried the code below on Windows 10:

```
import os
import ctypes

# Create a folder, make sub_folders in it and hide them
try:
    rootpath = "path/to/folder"
    os.mkdir(rootpath)
except OSError as e:
    print(e)  # So you'll know what the error is

for subfolder in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
    try:
        path = rootpath + "/" + subfolder  # Note, full path to the subfolder
        os.mkdir(path)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(path, 2)  # Hide folder
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)


# Remove a subfolder
os.rmdir(rootpath + "/" + "1")

# Add a new sub_folder
path = rootpath + "/" + "newsub"
os.mkdir(path)

# Hide the above newsub
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(path, 2)

# Unhide all the sub-folders in rootpath
subfolders = os.listdir(rootpath)

for sub in subfolders:
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(rootpath + "/" + sub, 1)
```

After running the above code, the subfolders in `rootpath` are:

```
>>> os.listdir(rootpath)
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'newsub']
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use os.makedirs.  Relevant documentation is

"os.makedirs?

Signature: os.makedirs(name, mode=511, exist_ok=False)
Docstring:
makedirs(name [, mode=0o777][, exist_ok=False])

create a leaf directory and all intermediate ones.  Works like
mkdir, except that any intermediate path segment (not just the rightmost)
will be created if it does not exist. If the target directory already
exists, raise an OSError if exist_ok is False. Otherwise no exception is
raised.  This is recursive."